# AG secondary DB files location

Tags: sql-server

I have two databases db-1 (primary) and db-2 secondary
now I moved all files location on DB-2 (system databases and default location in DB settings) to be :Q instead of :D
the problem is when I create new availability group on primary replica DB-1 I find that files created in old location (:D) on secondary replica !
how can I solve this issue so that when I create new AG files will be created automatically in the new drive :Q not :D on the secondary replica DB-2

**Thanks in advanced**

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour). We need to see exact error messages, relevant code snippets.

Comment: Thanks in *advanced*?

Answer (score 2):

If you want the file locations to be different on the secondary, which you should not do if possible, you must manually restore a backup of the primary database.  Instructions are here: [Prepare a secondary database for an Always On availability group](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/database-engine/availability-groups/windows/manually-prepare-a-secondary-database-for-an-availability-group-sql-server?view=sql-server-ver15)